# toastr: show after n seconds on pageload

Tags: javascript, css, toastr

I can't figure out how to show the toastr after 5 seconds when the was page loaded.

JS:

```
 $(function () {
 // Toastr options
 toastr.options = {
    "debug": false,
    "newestOnTop": false,
    "positionClass": "toast-top-center",
    "closeButton": true,
    "toastClass": "animated  fadeInDown",
     };
     setTimeout(function (){
    $('.homerDemo2')(function (){
    toastr.success('Success - This is a Homer success notification');
    }, 3000)
   });
   });
```

Comment: Pretty sure there is a syntax error in your code. Please indent correctly and ensure the code you are attempting to execute is correctly formatted.

Comment: What you mean by `$('.homerDemo2')(function (){`? This will never be executed. Type just `setTimeout(function () {    toastr.success('Success - This is a Homer success notification');    }, 3000);`

Answer (score 0):

I think you've mixed up the closing brackets on the end of your script.
Using a consistent coding-style shows where your brackets should go:

```
$(function () {
   // Toastr options
   toastr.options = {
      "debug": false,
      "newestOnTop": false,
      "positionClass": "toast-top-   center",
      "closeButton": true,
      "toastClass": "animated  fadeInDown",
   };

   setTimeout(function () {
      $('.homerDemo2')(function () {
         toastr.success('Success - This is a Homer success notification');
      });

   }, 3000);
});
```

**Edit**: `setTimeout` sets the timeout in milliseconds. So if you wish to display it after 5 seconds (not 3 in your example), set the timeout to `5000`.

Comment: thank you I'll try it later! Thank you, I knew about the time difference 3/5 seconds.

Comment: hi unfortunately it is not working the toastr doesnt show up.

Answer (score 0):

found the solution with toastr you basically define the onclick=null.

```
$(function () {
    // Toastr options
    toastr.options = {
        "closeButton": true,
        "debug": false,
        "newestOnTop": false,
        "progressBar": false,
        "positionClass": "toast-top-right",
        "preventDuplicates": false,
        "onclick": null,
        "showDuration": "3000",
        "hideDuration": "10000",
        "timeOut": "200000",
        "extendedTimeOut": "100000",
        "showEasing": "swing",
        "hideEasing": "linear",
        "showMethod": "fadeIn",
        "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
    }
    toastr.success("foo");

});
```